# Docker logs - Synchronize Time from Host to Container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I tried synchronising the timezone from host to container at runtime using:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/Data:/code/Data -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --restart unless-stopped intermediateservice
```

This does not appear to work as running the docker logs command:

```
docker logs -f -t zen_blackwell |tee output.log
```

Produces a timestamp (which is approximately 2 hours behind):

```
2021-01-13T10:43:22.372893697Z Ready...
```

This is incorrect as running the timedatectl command to check the current time on Host (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Bionic Beaver) produces:

```
timedatectl
                      Local time: Wed 2021-01-13 12:51:00 SAST
                  Universal time: Wed 2021-01-13 10:51:00 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2021-01-13 10:51:02
                       Time zone: Africa/Johannesburg (SAST, +0200)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

you can look at [this answer](https://forums.docker.com/t/synchronize-timezone-from-host-to-container/39116/3):

```
For the docker run -e TZ={timezone} workaround to work tzdata of course has to be installed in the container you’re trying to run.
What I was initially looking for (Docker container automatically having same timezone as host system) can be achieved through an ugly hack in the run script.
It can query geoip.ubuntu.com 172 (or any other geo IP database) once it is started on the new network and then set the server’s timezone based on the response: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/565139
```

the askubuntu code snippet is given here:

```
echo "Setting TimeZone..."
export tz=`wget -qO - http://geoip.ubuntu.com/lookup | sed -n -e 's/.*<TimeZone>\(.*\)<\/TimeZone>.*/\1/p'` &&  timedatectl set-timezone $tz
export tz=`timedatectl status| grep Timezone | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "TimeZone set to $tz"
```